# Can't install streamlit because packages don't match hashes from requirements file

Tags: python, caching, installation, pip, streamlit

Hey so i'm having issues installing streamlit in pip.
I have tried purging the cache installing with --no-cache-dir and neither worked.
still getting the following error each time after the streamlit installer tries to install pyarrow

```
ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
    pyarrow>=4.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/5b/cee81fdfbd963e08a50eda1500fc9142fa08a7dec5f7dcd9c7c2a33536b6/pyarrow-11.0.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (from streamlit):
        Expected sha256 ad7c53def8dbbc810282ad308cc46a523ec81e653e60a91c609c2233ae407689
             Got        4936d0fca47f9daf8c736bdd5d85b2e73fd5502fac748f2b169b04a58986c2e2
```